# Do we need thorax ct before all operations in covid days

Tags: covid-19

I am an anaesthetist,is pcr enough or do we have to look at the thorax tomography before surgeries

Answer (score 1):

This is an emerging area of advice.  It really depends on the pre-test probability of COVID-19 in your region, and the urgency of surgery.

The Royal College of Surgeons, Edinburgh make the following recommendation

9th April 2020

> Patients who present as abdominal emergencies who have an abdominal CT in their diagnostic investigations should also have a Chest CT scan (ref ––Updated General Surgery Guidance on Covid-19 – Intercollegiate / ASGBI 5th April 2020).
>
> Due to its low sensitivity and the low pre-test probability of disease (Scotland), computed tomography should only be deployed in very specific circumstances

Your pre-test probability may be much higher which might justify CT chest if you don't have time to do rtPCR, and antibody studies.

https://www.rcsed.ac.uk/news-public-affairs/news/2020/april/intercollegiate-guidance-for-pre-operative-chest-ct-imaging-for-elective-cancer-surgery-during-the-covid-19-pandemic

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment on rt-PCR.

Recent findings (which can be listened to in this [MedCram Youtube clip, by Roger Seheult, MD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5QJ5O3ldE0) on Covid-19 diagnosis), in summary says

> Lung ultrasound rivals CT imaging for fast and accurate bedside diagnosis and monitoring of coronavirus infection